# Assign Array Value to Variable and Insert into mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to save array value to variable so that I can insert that data/value into mysql using PHP for that I am using a pain taking long code so I want simple method to do it without writing it again and again.

Array shows data like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a><p class="wp-caption-text">Pendant Heart Images</p></div>
            [1] => a><p class="wp-caption-text">Pendant Heart Photos</p></div>
            [2] => a><p class="wp-caption-text">Pendant Heart Photos</p></div>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pendant Heart Images
            [1] => Pendant Heart Photos
            [2] => Pendant Heart Photos

      )

)
```

Code which I am using to save array value

```
$a = $g_img[1][0];
$b = $g_img[1][1];
$c = $g_img[1][2];

$a1 = $title[1][0];
$b1 = $title[1][1];
$c1 = $title[1][2];
```

Mysql query to save data

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data (Link, Title) VALUES ('$a','$a1')");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data (Link, Title) VALUES ('$b','$b1')");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO data (Link, Title) VALUES ('$c','$c1')");
```

So If array data increases I have to assign each array value to different variable which is huge process I know there would be a shortcut

Plz Help

Comment: How is that MySQL query supposed to work?

Comment: I have updated MySQL query check @TheWolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will not work because to start with, the number of field name are not equal to the number of values.

You could have passed your query in the following way:

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter <=2; $counter++){
    $query = "INSERT INTO data (Link, Title) VALUES ('{$g_img[1][$counter]}', '{$title[1][$counter]}')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

}
```

Here I have assumed that `$g_img` and `$title` correspond to the array of links and titles respectively and the data connection is `$con`.

Comment: yeah thanks it's working for me tell me if array increases from 2 to 10 should I change <=2 to <=10

Comment: How to ignore empty array like if array [1][0] => empty

Comment: The function count() will help you in this too just put it in an if-conditional.